# TestCafe: Text entered in textfield is backwards

Tags: google-chrome, automated-tests, textfield, e2e-testing, testcafe

Entering text into a textfield is entered backwards

This does not happen in Safari and hasn't happened in the past. No changes were made that should have caused this.

TestCafe 1.2.0
NPM 6.9.0

export async function logInMyAccount(emailElement, userEmail, passElement, userPassword, button) {
  await t
    .typeText(Selector(emailElement), userEmail, { startPos: 0 })
    .typeText(Selector(passElement), userPassword)
    .click(Selector(button));
}

await funct.logInMyAccount('#username', active.email , '#userpass', active.password, '#signIn');

should enter email as: active@mysite.com
actual email entered:  moc.etisym@evitca

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue described in this thread:

[typeText with Chrome 75 types each character at beginning of input](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3865)

The fix was included in TestCafe v1.2.1.